# Reading a list of numbers and sorting C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to read a list of numbers from a file and sort them by reading them into an array and then sorting the contents of the array. But I'm getting

```
error:incompatible types in assignment of 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' to 'int [1]'
```

I'm fairly new to programming and this is my first time working with C++ 
Can anyone tell me how to write the list of numbers to an array so that I can sort them? 
Here is what I have:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define ANYSIZE_ARRAY 1
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
  const char* filename = "test.txt";
  std::ifstream inputFile(filename);
  int numbers[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
  int i, key;

  // Make sure the file exists
  if(!inputFile)
  {
    cout << endl << "The File is corrupt or does not exist. " << filename;
    return 1;
  }

  long n = 0;
  while(!inputFile.eof())
  {
    inputFile >> n;
    numbers = cout << std::setw(10) << n;
  }

  for(int j=1;j<5;j++)
    {
        i=j-1;
        key=numbers[j];
        while(i>=0 && numbers[i]>key)
        {
                    numbers[i+1]=numbers[i];
                    i--;
        }
        numbers[i+1]=key;
    }

    //Display sorted array
    cout<<endl<<"Sorted Array\t";
     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       cout<<numbers[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your array `numbers` is too small for the number of rows you're trying to read into it.  The `1` in `int[1]` in the error message let's us know that there's a problem in the `for` loop at the end where you're trying to output 5 values from a 1-value array.  It would be worth printing the unsorted array before you sort it.  And ultimately, you will want to use the standard `sort` template function.  And maybe a vector of `int` to dynamically allocate entries as you go.

Comment: How many numbers are in the file? Is it a constant amount?

Comment: @Ove currently there are 20 numbers in the file but I would like it to take a variable so that it does not have to be constant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think I am going to go with using the sort function and vectors. After looking at the answer given by awoodland using vectors and doing some research they seem to be much easier use for my needs. Thanks for the info. I did get it to work my initial way too. I'm slowly starting to learn C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line causing the error is:

```
numbers = cout << std::setw(10) << n;
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, it looks like you just want to print it in which case the `numbers =` isn't needed.

The structure of your loop to read all the data is problematic also. The line: `while (!inputFile.eof())` isn't idiomatic C++ and *won't* do what you hope. [See here for a discussion on that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) (and [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5)).

For reference you can do this quite simply with less work by using `std::sort`

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("test.txt");
  // Skip checking it

  std::vector<int> numbers;

  // Read all the ints from in:
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            std::back_inserter(numbers));

  // Sort the vector:
  std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

  // Print the vector with tab separators: 
  std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This program also uses a `std::vector` instead of an array to abstract the "how big should my array be?" problem (which your example looked to have a possible problem problem with).

Comment: wow this is amazing! I had to look up a few things to understand how this worked but this seems like its alot easier than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do to get your program to work:

- Change `ANYSIZE_ARRAY` to **5**
- Where you read the numbers, replace the `while` with this:

  ```
  long n = 0;
  i=0;
  while(!inputFile.eof())
  {
          inputFile >> n;
          cout << std::setw(10) << n;
          numbers[i]=n;
          i++;
  }
  ```

This way, you will create an array which can hold 5 numbers, and you will read the numbers into that array. I used 5 because I saw that you were using the same number in the sorting algorithm, so I assumed that you only have to read 5 numbers. This is a bad thing, because your program will only work with 5 numbers.

If you need it to work with a variable amount of numbers, you can use a [`std::vector<long>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) to store the numbers. You can create a vector, and then use `push_back()` to add numbers to it. The vector will resize automatically and will hold as many numbers as you put in it. Then you can replace the `5`s in your code with the vector's `size()` method.

You were getting your original error because this line doesn't make sense:

```
numbers = cout << std::setw(10) << n;
```

C++ views that line as if you are trying to print out the number to the stdout stream (which is in our case the console, the screen), and then assigning that stream to the "numbers" array. You cannot assign an output stream to an integer array (hence the error cannot convert from ostream to int[1]).

Comment: Thanks! I need to mess with my compiler I think because after making the changes you suggested and build and run I get "Process terminated with status 255"  It goes through about halfway so it works, just doesn't finish.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not assign an outstream variable to an int.
Second, n is long type and numbers is an integer array. There is type-unsafety.
Third, you should pre-allocate array size.
Forth, you can directly use sort() in STL function to do the sorting.

Try the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define ANYSIZE_ARRAY 5

int main()
{
const char* filename = "test.txt";
std::ifstream inputFile(filename);
int numbers[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
int i, key;

// Make sure the file exists
if(!inputFile)
{
    cout << endl << "The File is corrupt or does not exist. " << filename;
    return 1;
}

int n = 0;
i = 0;
while(!inputFile.eof())
{
    inputFile >> n;
    cout << std::setw(10) << n;
    numbers[i++] = n;
}

sort(numbers, numbers + ANYSIZE_ARRAY);


//Display sorted array
cout<<endl<<"Sorted Array\t";
for(i=0; i<ANYSIZE_ARRAY; i++)
    cout<<numbers[i]<<"\t";

cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works but like awoodland shows, while(!inputFile.eof()) is not idiomatic C++ So I probably need to use another way of doing that.